# Recyclerview scroll item to top and scroll a bit more for the size of a view inside

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I have a recyclerview with a custom LinearLayoutManager which enables me to scroll to the selected item and snapping that item to the start of the recyclerview. However the items are divided into categories and the first items in each category has a header textview. I want to scroll past the header when the smoothscrolling occurs.
Basically this is I get. The headers are only textview in the items and are only visible if the item is first in a category.

Instead of seeing this;

```
#HeaderForItem1
##ITEM1
##ITEM2
#HeaderForItem3
###ITEM3
###ITEM4
###ITEM5
```

I want to scroll past the header too and see this; when I scroll to ITEM1

```
##ITEM1
##ITEM2
#HeaderForItem3
###ITEM3
###ITEM4
###ITEM5
```

I've tried getting all the views inside the customlayoutmanager's onLayoutComplete method and find the headers height dynamically. Which I've managed to get but wasn't able to add to the scrolling

Here is my customlayoutmanager

```
internal class LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller : LinearLayoutManager {

    private var offset = 0
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(
        context,
        VERTICAL,
        false
    ) {
    }

    // map of child adapter position to its height.
    private val childSizesMap = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()

    override fun onLayoutCompleted(state: State?) {
        super.onLayoutCompleted(state)
        val view = getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
        val v = view.getChildAt(0)
        offset = v.height
    }

    override fun smoothScrollToPosition(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State,
        position: Int
    ) {
        val smoothScroller: SmoothScroller = TopSnappedSmoothScroller(recyclerView.context)
        smoothScroller.targetPosition = position
        startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
    }

    private inner class TopSnappedSmoothScroller(context: Context?) :
        LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
        override fun computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition: Int): PointF? {
            return this@LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller
                .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition)
        }

        override fun getVerticalSnapPreference(): Int {
            return SNAP_TO_START
        }
    }
}
```

and I basically call smoothScrollToPosition(position) from the activity.

Can you guys direct me about how I shall proceed?

Thanks in advance.